# Symfony2 Capistrano deploying to CDN

Tags: symfony, deployment, capistrano, cdn, capifony

I've got a Symfony2 application which I am deploying to development, staging and production servers using Capistrano. However, I'm looking to also setup a CDN to serve static content such as images, css, js files etc. The URL for the CDN for example is static.example.com. I've read that I simply need to add the following to my config_prod.yml file:

```
framework:
     templating:
         engines: ['twig']
         assets_base_urls:
         http: [http://static.example.com]
```

However, when deploying using capistrano would I need to deploy the whole application to the CDN as well as the server that will host the website or can I deploy only the assets i.e images, js files etc to the CDN and the dynamic files to the server/s?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Only static assets needs to be served by your CDN.

See also:
[automatic push to CDN deployment strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786540/automatic-push-to-cdn-deployment-strategy)

Comment: Thanks. What if we've got 2 servers and we need somewhere to share uploaded content to the server? I.e if a user uploads an image and they are currently on server 1, how does server 2 access this file? Wouldnt you need to upload this image to the CDN?

Comment: Also, I've read the link you gave, how does the CDN do the pull request? Do you need to install something on the CDN?

Comment: I would assume files uploaded by users would need to be added to a content repository from which server 1 and server 2 would pull similar assets. The pull would occur from the original server (hosting dynamically generated contents which would then be statically served by the CDN).

http://www.whoishostingthis.com/blog/2010/06/30/cdns-push-vs-pull/