# Symfony2 + Capifony Doctrine migrations

Tags: symfony, deployment, doctrine, capistrano, capifony

I've installed the DoctrineMigrationsBundle to my Symfony2 app, however when I try to deploy to my development server I'm getting the following error:

```
    Do you really want to migrate dev's database? (y/N)
y
  * executing "sh -c ' cd /var/www/vhosts/xyz.co.uk/releases/20130413181722 && php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --env=dev --no-interaction'"
    servers: ["x.xx.xx.xxx"]
    [x.xx.xx.xxx] executing command
 ** [out :: x.xx.xx.xxx]                                                               
 ** [out :: x.xx.xx.xxx]                     Application Migrations                    
 ** [out :: x.xx.xx.xxx]                                                               
 ** [out :: x.xx.xx.xxx] 
 ** [out :: x.xx.xx.xxx] Migrating up to 0 from 0
 ** [out :: x.xx.xx.xxx] 
 ** [out :: x.xx.xx.xxx] 
 ** [out :: x.xx.xx.xxx]                                                  
 ** [out :: x.xx.xx.xxx]   [Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\MigrationException]  
 ** [out :: x.xx.xx.xxx]   Could not find any migrations to execute.      
 ** [out :: x.xx.xx.xxx]                                                  
 ** [out :: x.xx.xx.xxx] 
 ** [out :: x.xx.xx.xxx] 
 ** [out :: x.xx.xx.xxx] doctrine:migrations:migrate [--write-sql] [--dry-run] [--configuration[="..."]] [--db-configuration[="..."]] [--em[="..."]] [version]
 ** [out :: x.xx.xx.xxx] 
 ** [out :: x.xx.xx.xxx] 
    command finished in 802ms
*** [symfony:doctrine:migrations:migrate] rolling back
Do you really want to migrate dev's database back to version 0? (y/N)
```

Any idea what's causing this?

Here is my deploy.rb file:

```
set :stage_dir, 'app/config/deploy'
set :stages, %w(production staging development)
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'

set :application,           "xyz.co.uk"
set :user,                  "deployer"  # The server's user for deploys

set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false

set :repository,            "git@github.xyz/xyz.co.uk.git"
set :scm,                   :git
set :keep_releases,         3
after "deploy:update",      "deploy:cleanup"
set :use_sudo,              false
set :web_path,              "web"
set :shared_files,          ["app/config/parameters.yml"]
set :shared_children,       [app_path + "/logs", web_path + "/uploads"]
set :use_composer,          true
set :update_vendors,        true
set :dump_assetic_assets,   true
set :deploy_via,            :remote_cache

#logger.level = Logger::MAX_LEVEL

before "symfony:cache:warmup", "symfony:doctrine:migrations:migrate"

after "deploy:update_code" do
  capifony_pretty_print "--> Ensuring cache directory permissions"
  run "setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX #{latest_release}/#{cache_path}"
  run "setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX #{latest_release}/#{cache_path}"
  capifony_puts_ok
end
```

**UPDATE**

The issue was because I hadn't commited the doctrine migration version files and pushed them to GitHub. Is this the correct process after making a change to an entity:

```
php app/console doctrine:migrations:diff 
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force 
git add app/DoctrineMigrations/Version1234.php 
git commit -a -m "migration" 
git push origin develop 
cap development deploy
```

Comment: Have you check the migration_versions table ?

Comment: Yes, there was nothing in there. I've fixed it now, I hadn't committed the version files from my local machine to GitHub. I've updated my original question, can you please confirm the process is correct? (BOttom of original question)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` but `php app/console doctrine:migration:migrate`.

And you may use `cap development deploy:migrations` in order to execute the migrations after the deployment.

Hope it's helpful.
Best regard.

Comment: Thanks. Few questions:
1. Do you have to add each version to GitHUb? I suppose you do.
2. If you use `cap development deploy:migrations` does that mean I wouldn't need before "symfony:cache:warmup", "symfony:doctrine:migrations:migrate" in my deploy.rb script? So you deploy and then migrate? 
3. If the answer to 2 is yes, then should you put a maintenance page up when you deploy until the migrations are complete?

Thanks again.

Comment: 1. Yes because your code is clone from github.
2. Yes I think so.
3. It's depends of your application. If your migrations script is very long or complex, you can use this bundle https://github.com/lexik/LexikMaintenanceBundle

Comment: I don't suppose you can help with this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943276/symfony2-capistrano-deploying-to-cdn :)